# How do I click to hide white space between pages in Print Layout view?

Tags: microsoft-word

I already know, and ask not about, how to [Uncheck the box to the left of **Show white space between pages in Print Layout view**.](https://www.live2tech.com/hide-white-space-pages-print-layout-word-2013/).

Joan Lambert. [*Microsoft Word 2019 Step by Step*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1509305874). [p. 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=4PiFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&lpg=PT95&dq=%22to+hide+or+display+white+space+in+print+layout+view%22&source=bl&ots=mDMHGEi_Zv&sig=ACfU3U3BWfLhZywGOqQ9onJidUCVMg1s5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCz5TplaniAhXQxVkKHWu8DkEQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22to%20hide%20or%20display%20white%20space%20in%20print%20layout%20view%22&f=false).

> [image]

Pls see [GIF beneath](https://mega.nz/#!D5QyXArS!PrNMtdbHGZCVKzBEw_bmXF-0-vJP-Z8Orj_sSk25Vuo). I followed Lambert's instructions but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on the space *between* the pages. You should see a little icon that looks like this:

[image: Double-click to hide white space]